# Как в css наложить два слоя

Tags: html, css

[image]

Всем привет! помогите пожалуйста сделать как на фото с двумя слоями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.card IMG { position: relative; }
.card1 { width: 150px; top: 50px; left: 55px; z-index: 3; }
.card2 { width: 150px; left: -120px; top: 25px; z-index: 2; }
.card3 { width: 150px; left: -295px; z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<p class="card">
   <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/shift-free/32/Block-512.png" class="card1" />
   <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/shift-free/32/Block-512.png" class="card2" />
   <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/shift-free/32/Block-512.png" class="card3" />
  </p>
```

Используй `z-index` и `position`